# PHP regex not working - returns NULL on local server, but works properly on other

Tags: php, regex

I have following regex:

```
/\{\s?joomla-tag\s+(.*<+.+>+.*)\s?\}/is
```

and the following code:

```
$regex = "/\{\s?joomla-tag\s+(.*<+.+>+.*)\s?\}/is";
$replace = '<div class="someclass">$1</div>';
$text = preg_replace( $regex, $replace, $text );
```

But, unfortunately, it cannot match the following code (nevertheless it should):

```
.... many html lines .......
<p>123{joomla-tag Lore<strong>m</strong> ip</p>
<p>sum dolor sit amet}</p>
.... many html lines .......
```

**See the real sample:** http://pastebin.com/WSQyrmxd

What's wrong: regular expression or something else? Could you please advise the correct variant?
In RegExr, everything works smoothly, but not in PHP.

**On a local server, i simply get NULL after preg_replace**

---

**EDIT:** 
Finally I found a solution: (thanks, **sg3s**, for an idea)
http://www.pelagodesign.com/blog/2008/01/25/wtf-preg_replace-returns-null/

Comment: Must be the regular expression.

Comment: I don't think you need to use `\{`

Comment: they are necessary, i need to match {joomla-tag ..... }

Comment: I just did a copy and paste and it worked fine for me.

Comment: no, it doesn't for me. What could be the reason?

Comment: its working here properly http://codepad.org/h1lIkhqF

Comment: I see. Could many other html tags surrounding this be the reason why this is not working in real app?

Comment: What isn't working as you would expect?

Comment: No mathches - no replacements at all

Comment: Can you provide a real sample of text that doesn't produce any matches / replacements?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/WSQyrmxd   line 200

Comment: I might note that this kind of regex on this large a string is very resource demanding; my test app for this regex literally said it wasn't very happy with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say you solved the problem, but if your solution was to increase the `backtrack_limit` setting, that's not a solution.  In fact, you're probably setting yourself up for bigger problems later on.  You need to find out **why** it's doing so much backtracking.

After `\{\s?joomla-tag\s+` locates the beginning of the tag, the first `.*` initially gobbles up the remainder of the document.  Then it starts backing off, trying to let the rest of the regex match.  When it reaches a point where `<+` can match, the `.+` again consumes the rest of the document, and another wave of backtracking begins.  And with yet another `.*` after that, you're making it do a ridiculous amount of unnecessary work.

This is the reason for the rule of thumb,

> Don't use the dot metacharacter (especially `.*` or `.+`) if you can use something more specific.  If you do use the dot, don't use it in single-line or DOTALL mode (i.e., the `/s` modifier or its inline, `(?s)` form).

In this case, you know the match should end at the next closing brace (`}`), so don't let it match any braces before that:

```
\{\s?joomla-tag\s+([^}]*)\}
```

Comment: Yes! The original expression has _much_ room for improvement, backtracking-wise. +1

Comment: +1. One question though: Does using the non-greedy `.*?` help there, given that it wouldn’t eat up the rest of the document?

Comment: If the closing `}` is present, `.*?` will definitely be more efficient than `.*`.  If it's missing, `.*?` will keep going until the end of the document before it gives up.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like this may be a: `pcre.recursion_limit` error due to the PCRE regex engine running out of stack. I've seen this before (but typically the symptoms are more severe - i.e. completely crashing the webserver!) Note that this class of problem will frequently manifest symptoms on a local server and not a remote server, particularly if the local system is running Apache under Windows (The Win32 build of `httpd.exe` has only 256KB of stack space).

`preg_replace()` returns `NULL` when it encounters an error in the PCRE library. You can use the `preg_last_error()` function to get the last error and print out a message like so:

```php
   $pcre_err = preg_last_error();  // PHP 5.2 and above.
    if ($pcre_err === PREG_NO_ERROR) {
        $msg = 'Successful non-match.';
    } else {
        // preg_match error!
        switch ($pcre_err) {
            case PREG_INTERNAL_ERROR:
                $msg = 'PREG_INTERNAL_ERROR';
                break;
            case PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR:
                $msg = 'PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR';
                break;
            case PREG_RECURSION_LIMIT_ERROR:
                $msg = 'PREG_RECURSION_LIMIT_ERROR';
                break;
            case PREG_BAD_UTF8_ERROR:
                $msg = 'PREG_BAD_UTF8_ERROR';
                break;
            case PREG_BAD_UTF8_OFFSET_ERROR:
                $msg = 'PREG_BAD_UTF8_OFFSET_ERROR';
                break;
            default:
                $msg = 'Unrecognized PREG error';
                break;
        }
    }
    echo($msg);
```

I've explained this error in detail with answers to related questions. See:

[RegExp in preg_match function returning browser error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7627962/433790)

[PHP regex: is there anything wrong with this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5527831/433790)

[Minifying final HTML output using regular expressions with CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5324014/433790)

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

It [works for me](http://codepad.org/cqUQW092).

Note that from an HTML standpoint, your replacement does not create a valid structure.

#### Using the full text

It still [works for me](http://codepad.org/8dxWnF5F), even with the provided full HTML example. So there has to be somethign wrong with your other code; you might want to enable full error output to see if there’s some other issue.

Comment: yes, I know. But that will be handled further. Now I need to get this working

Comment: Strange really... Can it be caused by encoding?

Comment: On a local server, i simply get NULL after preg_replace

Comment: The demo text you provided works as well with this regex. http://codepad.org/EXskRfl1 search for "Cool and nice" -> the problem lies somewhere else.